# How to issue a multipart/form-data request of a file and a duplicate key with curl on php

Tags: php, curl

I'd like to know if it's possible to issue the following `multipart/form-data` request by relying on `PHP`'s `curl` automatic body creation from the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option. I'd like to avoid building the body string myself.

```
POST / HTTP/1.0
Host: example.com
Content-type: multipart/form-data, boundary=AaB03x
Content-Length: ...

--AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field"

foo
--AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field"

bar
--AaB03x
content-disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="filename"
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

...
```

Notice how `"field"` appear twice. The API I'm dealing with requires that array be specified as duplicate (e.g `field=foo&field=bar`) and doesn't accept the `PHP` way of serializing such structure (e.g `field[0]=foo&field[1]=bar`).

From what I understand the correct way of `POST`ing files with `curl` on `PHP` is using a `CurlFile`:

```
$ch = curl_init();
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt(
    $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    array('file' => new CurlFile('file.txt', 'text/plain', 'file.txt'))
);
```

The thing is I can't specify a duplicate `POST` field this way. I tried providing an array of value but it fails miserably with an `Array to string conversion` exception.

```
$ch = curl_init();
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt(
    $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
        'fields' => array('foo', 'bar'),
        'file' => new CurlFile('file.txt', 'text/plain', 'file.txt'),
    )
);
...
Array to string conversion
```

Is there any way I can achieve what I'm after or do I have to build my `multipart` request by myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this [is a PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51634).